# What can you do with the vector inproduct/outproduct?

Tags: linear-algebra

I had an assignment with the following question.

What is the inproduct and outproduct of these two vectors, I could't find a translation for inproduct and outproduct so it might be called different.

```
|1|       |2|   
|1|  and  |1|
|1|       |0|
```

The solution for the inprodcut was:

```
1*2 + 1*1 + 1*0 = 2 + 1 + 0 = 3
```

//I guess x1 * y1 + x2 * y2 + x3 * y3

The solution for the oudproduct:

```
 |1*0 - 1*1|    |0-1|   |-1|
 |1*2 - 1*0| =  |2-0| = | 1|
 |1*1 - 1*2|    |1-2|   |-1|
```

What is the logic behind the values chosen for the formulas and what can I do with the inpproduct and outproduct?

Comment: These are typically called the Dot Product (Inner or In-Product) and Cross Product (Outer or Out-Product); try reading the wikipedia pages and see if they give you any insight.

Comment: @AlexanderHeyes thanks, so the dotproduct is the length of a vector?

Comment: The dot product of a vector  v with itself is the square of the distance from v to the zero-vector.